# Change screen preferences

Tags: android

I have a business requirement, and after lot of googling came to a point that android (as compared to iPhone) would be the platform to go for

I have a requirement wherein lets say an App 'X' that comes built-in with OS (firmware) needs to be replaced with some App 'Y'.

Of course, i understand that there would be something that i would need to change at firmware level (correct me), and of course i have no idea how to do that

So, is such a kind of thing even possible ?

Any links where i could look for more.

Yogurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your app provides the same functionality and it reacts on all intents, you could just delete the native apk from system/app and put your own apk there.

Comment: Is that really possible? I mean deleting a native app from system/app

Comment: It's possible if you have root access on the device.

Comment: Things that would be required to have root access ?

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar project in the past. The solution was to install our app in addition to the "native" one and to catch and process all input (notifications, broadcasts, etc) in our application. It also might be possible to prevent native application from reacting to those inputs.

Comment: Any way to replace App 'X' with 'Y'

Comment: I think that the only way is to rebuild the whole system, which is not an easy task. Would be happy to learn about another (easier) option myself.

Comment: So, to rebuild whole system, access to actual firmware would be needed right, which seems highly impossible being at the App-Developer side, right ? Or may be some other way to rebuild the system ?

Comment: is getting the code at source.android.com the only option (i am assuming that i can tweak the code according to requirements and then build from the code and then load on phone , pls correct me ?), or maybe there could be something else.

Comment: It might be not the only option but I cannot recommend you any other way.